# How to include a function in multiple pages in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a function that I would like to load in multiple pages inside the app instead of repeating them individually in each .ts file.

Comment: You can create BasePage and each one of you pages can extends it and will get all the functions in it. In addition, you can call the parent in the each page and there putting all your functions calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a new file with a public class. Then import that file everywhere you want and use the functions you need.

for example : **myFunctions.ts**

```
export class MyFunctions {
  private message:string = 'It works!';

  constructor(){

  }

  public aFirstFunction(){
    console.log(this.message);
  }
}
```

Then in any file you want :

```
import {MyFunctions} from 'path/to/myFunctions.ts';
```

and

```
private hereAreMyFunctions = new MyFunctions();

private function tryIt() {
  this.hereAreMyFunctions.aFirstFunction();
}
```

Then just call `tryIt()` ;)

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'aFirstFunction' of undefined

Comment: My bad, I forgot an important part. I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: You can try again! Tell me if another error appear ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and cleanest way is to use a static method. I usually use a static function as a "util method".

```
export class DateUtils{
   static myUtilFunction(arg: Date){
     let result;
     // your imlementation  
     //......
     //......
     return result;
   }
}
```

Whenever you want to use it you can simply call it as:

```
let result = DateUtils.myUtilFunction(myDate);
```